# Why Are Empirical Bayes Methods Not Considered "Controversial"?

Tags: bayesian, prior, empirical-bayes

I was reading about Empirical Bayesian Methods and came across the following:

[image]

**My Question:** As this text explains, I have often heard that the priors used in Bayesian Methods should be decided prior to seeing any data - however, it seems that Empirical Bayesian Methods seem to outright go against this and choose priors based on the data. Does anyone know why they do this and what are the advantages/disadvantages of doing this compared to the traditional Bayesian Approach?

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method

Comment: I don't think Empirical Bayes is as wild as the description seems.  Typically you would specify a hierarchical model with a vague prior on the model parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$, and the hyper parameters themselves, $\boldsymbol{\eta}$, would have a vague hyper prior distribution.  The data is used to update the hyper priors and this cascades down to the prior for $\boldsymbol{\theta}$.  Empirical Bayes just simplifies the process a bit by plugging in a data-dependent point estimate for $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ instead of turning a hyper prior into a data-dependent hyper posterior.